# Is it possible to view hardware-reported device identifiers on Windows ME?

Tags: hardware, windows-me

On Windows XP and later you can view OS device identifiers for a given hardware component in Device Manager; those often include hardware-reported device identifiers, like PCI vendor/product ID pairs.

Is this possible to look up the latter in Windows ME?  I didn't find it.

Also see this image: [screenshot of hardware IDs](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/support/us/en/images/boardsandkits/devmgr-hardwareID-nuc.jpg)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The operating system’s device tree can be enumerated by looking it up directly in the Registry under the key `HKEY_DYN_DATA\Config Manager\Enum`.  Each direct subkey corresponds to a loaded device driver; in particular the `HardWareKey` value of each subkey contains an identifier, which for PCI devices usually contains VID/PID pairs, and usually corresponds to a subkey of `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Enum`.  In the latter key’s `DeviceDesc` value, you can look up the device name as it appears in Device Manager.  The difference between those keys is pretty straightforward: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Enum` covers all installed drivers, while `HKEY_DYN_DATA\Config Manager\Enum` only covers drivers that are currently loaded.  This is best seen when the system is running in Safe Mode.

Comment: I did not need to look into "HKEY_DYN_DATA\Config Manager\Enum" but found all PCI devices and IDs under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Enum\PCI.